# TFS Database deploy solution

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, build

We are trying to come up with a way for our SQL Dev's and DBA's to do all SQL work in MS SQL Management Studio, and work this into a build/deploy process in TFS.

I know RedGate has SQL Source Control, and that lets us keep changes in Management Studio, but how do we incorporate this into a reliable overall build/deploy release workflow?

I don't want to make our SQL team use Visual Studio, their tool of choice is MSSMS.

Looking for some serious help and pointers here, but any help is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the SQL Compare Pro and SQL Data Compare Pro command lines to achieve this. An example of how these might be used as part of a build process can be found here:

http://downloads.red-gate.com/HelpPDF/ContinuousIntegrationForDatabasesUsingRedGateSQLTools.pdf